# Update row using sqlalchemy, marshmallow and flask?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am using flask, sqlalchemy and marshmallow, I have a table with data in place and POST, GET and DELETE work fine, I am having a problem to update the entire row by passing data as JSON, I am querying the row by customer column, tried all options that I could find, no real example in updating data from JSON, any help?

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

class Feedback(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    dealer = db.Column(db.String(200))
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text)

def __init__(self, customer, dealer, rating, comments): 
    self.customer = customer
    self.dealer = dealer
    self.rating = rating
    self.comments = comments

class FeedbackSchema(ma.Schema): 
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'customer', 'dealer', 'rating', 'comments')

feedback_schema = FeedbackSchema()
feedbacks_schema = FeedbackSchema(many=True) 

@app.route('/updateReview', methods=['PUT'])
def updateReview():
    customer = request.args['customer']
    if customer == '':
        return 'Bad request, please enter Customer', 404
    customer = request.json['customer']
    dealer = request.json['dealer']
    rating = request.json['rating']
    comments = request.json['comments']
    update_customer = Feedback(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
    cus = Feedback.query.filter_by(customer=customer).first()
    cus.update(update_customer)
    db.session.commit()
    return 'ok'
```

Comment: What is the error/output? Does the function just run fine but the DB is updated?

Comment: I get a 500 server error

Comment: You can use `schema.load(request.get_json(), instance=instance)` to update (with marshmallow sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the way you are creating the `update_customer` and way you are trying to update the `cus`.

Try this one.

```
feedback = Feedback.query.filter_by(customer=customer).first()

feedback.customer = customer
feedback.dealer = dealer
feedback.rating = rating
feedback.comments = comments

db.session.add(feedback)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: What's the point in using an ORM if I manually update each field in the row?

Comment: @guzdo As per my understanding ORM only takes care of Object interactions with DB. It is not responsible for the current state of the Object.